# Does Rails streaming need to finish template generation to output the template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, http-live-streaming, hamlit

I've been setting up [Rails streaming](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Streaming.html). I have it working so that the top of the layout is rendered immediately, but when it outputs the template, it seems to process the whole template before flushing it.

e.g. Let's say I have a standard layout with  etc, then I have a template like this, with a simulated pause in the middle:

```
content start
<% sleep 5 %>
content end
```

Now when I curl this, I will see:

```
<html>
  <head>
     <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>

  (.. 5 seconds later ..)

     content start
     content end
  </body>
</html>
```

Is this expected behaviour? I thought it would render the template as it's being processed. ([Hamlit](https://github.com/k0kubun/hamlit) is the template engine, if that matters.)